# Do you have to accept an answer?

Tags: discussion

i have 2 questions, one has one answer, that makes sense but assumes the game uses a random decision. now the problem with that is that i can't really verify this. should i accept the answer based on being the only one and making sense?

My second question got 3 answers, and all of them are correct. i'm not sure if that makes my question subjective, but would it be ok if i accept the one that would be best for me (so subjectifly accepting the answer?) or leave it open since all 3 answers are correct and diffrent approaches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not necessary to put the checkmark on an answer - just be aware that, when you have enough questions, your "accept rate" ratio will show up.

If this accept ratio is too low, users will generally stop answering you and request that you go back and accept some questions beforehand.

Re: your specific cases.

- I realize [my answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12912/what-happens-if-two-upgrades-tie/12913#12913) is not easy at all to verify here. "Random" is just the safe bet; programmers would say [the behavior is undefined](http://www.olc.edu/~cdelong/jargon-4.4.7/jargon-4.4.7/html/N/nasal-demons.html); we can only imagine how the game is coded because the devs are explicitly vague on all the corner cases. I think it's okay to not accept anything here.
- For [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12798/how-to-go-against-near-end-game-all-for-one-tactics), since the answers are actually different, I'd try and pick the most effective one. If all else fails, consider making a community wiki summary answer, then accept that one.